# How can I read in a data table with the first column name missing?

Tags: r, read.table

I want to read in the data set from this website into R: https://socialsciences.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Applied-Regression-2E/datasets/Cowles.txt

There is an ID column without a column name in the first column. How can I either not read in the ID column or read in the ID column with a blank/new title?

Answer (score 2):

## import all columns (then change name)

```
# load package
library(data.table)

# import txt
df <- fread("https://socialsciences.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Applied-Regression-2E/datasets/Cowles.txt")

# change 1st column's name
names(df)[1] <- 'id'
```

## import all except 1st column

```
df <- fread("https://socialsciences.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Applied-Regression-2E/datasets/Cowles.txt", drop = 1)
```

Comment: Using `file.choose()` is not reproducible. Instead it would be better to just use the URL.

Comment: updated to use URL

Answer (score 1):

We can use `setnames` to change the first column's name (which is automatically named `V1`) when you read in the file, and do it all in one step:

```
library(data.table)

dt <-
  setnames(
    fread(
      "https://socialsciences.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Applied-Regression-2E/datasets/Cowles.txt"
    ),
    "V1",
    "ID"
  )
```

**Output**

```
        ID neuroticism extraversion    sex volunteer
   1:    1          16           13 female        no
   2:    2           8           14   male        no
   3:    3           5           16   male        no
   4:    4           8           20 female        no
   5:    5           9           19   male        no
  ---                                               
1417: 1417           5           10   male       yes
1418: 1418           8            4 female       yes
1419: 1419           8            8   male       yes
1420: 1420          19           20 female       yes
1421: 1421          15           20   male       yes
```

If you want to ignore the first column, then you can either use `drop` (as suggested in the other answer), or you can also use `select` to keep the columns that you want.

```
dt <- fread(
  "https://socialsciences.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Applied-Regression-2E/datasets/Cowles.txt", select = c(2:5)
)

      neuroticism extraversion    sex volunteer
   1:          16           13 female        no
   2:           8           14   male        no
   3:           5           16   male        no
   4:           8           20 female        no
   5:           9           19   male        no
  ---                                          
1417:           5           10   male       yes
1418:           8            4 female       yes
1419:           8            8   male       yes
1420:          19           20 female       yes
1421:          15           20   male       yes
```